# Django project won't run on ubuntu with additional installed apps

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

My setup

- Local machine 10.9.3
- Django 1.6.2 - local machine
- Server Ubuntu 12.04
- Django 1.6 - ubuntu server

When deploying a django project to a server running Ubunto 12.04 I found that having an additional, but non existent application listed in my `INSTALLED_APPS` section of my `settings.py` file prevented me from using any of the `python manage.py` commands.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'survey',
    'django_countries',
)
```

In this case I had previously had a `django_countries` application in the project which I subsequently deleted. However that never prevented me from being able to use any of the `python manage.py` commands on my local machine `OSX 10.9.3`

However when I uploaded the project to my production server it would give me errors e.g. running `python manage.py runserver`

would get me

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_countries
```

Of course removing the unnecessary `django_countries` app in the `settings.py` solved my problem but I would like to know: Why is it different between the two environments? are there significant other differences that I should watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

That's a completely expected behaviour - `INSTALLED_APPS` defines which applications you have installed and Django tries to find theirs models, urls etc. If it can't find anything *installed*, you'll get this error. Either remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` or install it.

Also it looks like you don't use VirtualEnv. Learn how to use it and use it for every project otherwise you'll get nuts soon .)

Comment: As per my question: "Of course removing the unnecessary django_countries app in the settings.py solved my problem but I would like to know: Why is it different between the two environments?" Thanks for the tip regarding `virtualenv` Ive been using it for a while now and find it excellent.

Comment: well the difference is that `django_countries` is not bundled in your system in default and you (or someone) installed it on one of your machines but not on the another.

Comment: So even though I had deleted it from my project several weeks ago it was still finding it on my system and therefore was allowing it to run locally. But when i uploaded the project it was not able to find it.